# How do I get the parameters of a MySQL function in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, regex, function, parameters

I'm looking for an way to get the parameters of an MySQL function and put them in an array in PHP. Example:

```
$field = "CONCAT(fieldA, ' ', fieldB)";
```

What I have done so far is:

```
preg_match("/^([A-Z_]*)\((.*)\)/", $field, $matches)
$parameters = explode(",", $matches[2]);
```

Which works fine for the example above. However trying the same solution for the following example:

```
$field = "CONCAT_WS(', ', fieldA, fieldB)";
```

Will result in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => '
    [1] =>  '
    [2] =>  fieldA
    [3] =>  fieldB
)
```

And I would like to get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ', '
    [1] =>  fieldA
    [2] =>  fieldB
)
```

I'm looking for an universal way of doing this, not just for the examples I've provided. It should work on all types of parameters; string, field names and functions.

Comment: I can't get this question. How to get parameters of a MySQL function.? For me this looks like [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Ok, I've elaborated my questing, I hope it's more clear now what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Regexp magician needed here :D

Answer (score 0):

You can concat it as you are and simply use an `array_filter($result)` on the result when you explode it - by not specifying a callback. An empty string will return false, so that will remove the ones that are causing problems. (If I am understanding your problem correctly)

Alternately, use a different separator and explode on that instead?

Edit: Based on your question, you could simply get the fields normally and return them as an array?

Based on PDO

```
<?php
    $sth = $dbh->prepare("select ', ' as f1, fieldA as f2, fieldB as f3 from tableName");
    $sth->execute();

    print("PDO::FETCH_BOTH: ");
    print("Return next row as an array indexed by both column name and number\n");
    $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
    print_r($result);
    print("\n");
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ', '
    [f1] => ', '
    [1] =>  fieldA
    [f2] =>  fieldA
    [2] =>  fieldB
    [f3] =>  fieldB
)
```

Comment: It's not just about the concat function. I'm looking for an universal way of getting the parameters and putting them into array.

Comment: @FredvanEtten Your update has confused me even more - see the edit.

Comment: @Fluffeh He just wants to parse the string and get all parameters out of it.

Comment: @DanLee I don't get the concat if the OP wants to then go through a lot of trouble to split it right afterwards?

Comment: @Fluffeh I think it hasn't even something to do with SQL but just plain text parsing. The most trouble he has is that there can be strings with a `,` inside, and this is splitted too with a simple explode.

Comment: @DanLee Possibly, but it seems a heck of a red herring to ask about parsing a string into an array.

Comment: @FredvanEtten Okay, I am not fantastic with parsing, but to help you get an answer to your question, you might want to pop in an example of what you would like to parse and how you would like to see the output - and maybe for good measure take out the references to databases - it threw me a total curveball.